# Determine whether there is linear independence or not

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Determine if the following set of vectors is linearly independent:

$$S =  \{e^x, e^{2x}\}$$ of continuous functions.

So my problem isn't in not knowing what linearly independence is, it is setting up a linear combination of this form:

$$a_1e^x + a_2e^{2x} = ????$$

What do I set it equal to to determine the coefficients? For example if it was in terms of vectors it would be something like:

$$a_1V_1 + a_2V_2 = (0,0,0,)$$ if I was in $R^3$ for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the vectors are **functions**.  What is the zero vector?  It is the function that takes all real numbers to $0$.

What you want to prove is that, for the functions $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$, if we have $a$ and $b$ such that $a e^x + b e^{2x} = 0$ (the zero function), then $a = b = 0$.

One way to show this would be to first plug in $x = 0$ to conclude $a + b = 0$.  Then take the derivative and plug in $0$ to conclude $a + 2b = 0$.

Comment: The one problem i may have with that is, that it requested that it is only a C(R) function, so i only have continuity. The space is  not stated as being differntiable. What could i do then?

Comment: @dc3rd you can just pick another point. Plugging in $x=1$ would yield $ae+be^2=0$, and you could use that with $a+b=0$ to determine $a=b=0$ instead.

Comment: Ah ok. I have another quick question wth regards to the same concept but it involves a set S = { (3)^1/2, e, pi}. So a set of constants. Now if i set it up in a linear combination, and try to solve for the coefficients, i would have for examlple  (3)^1/2 = (-a2/a1)e - (a3/a1) pi. Can i get away with this in contrast to the question above because this one does not require me using an independent value such as "x"?

Comment: @dc3rd The coefficients can be any real numbers, so yes, you can get away with values $a_1, a_2, a_3$ in that case but not in the case of functions.  It's the fact that it must be true *for all* $x$.

Comment: @dc3rd In regard to your first comment, in fact, it doesn't matter that $C(R)$ includes functions that aren't differentiable, because you know $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$ are differentiable.  All you have to prove is that the functions $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$ are linearly independent, and you can use anything you know about these functions to do so.  In particular you can use that they are differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Always the same thing, you set it equal to the zero vector.

In this case the "vectors" you are talking about are functions.  (Like $e^x$ for example.)  The "zero vector" is the function given by $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You would replace the question marks you above above with $0$. This zero isn't quite the same as an ordinary scalar zero (even though we write it the same way), rather it's the constant zero function. That is, it is the function $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

your matrix will be in a 2x2 form where row 1 is ae^x + be^2x = 0 and row 2 = e^x + 2e^2x =0, you find the determinant by factoring out e^x*e^(2x) multiplied by your simplified matrix with (1,1) and (1,2) as rows 1 and 2. Hence determinant is e^x*e^(2x)* (2-1)= e^x*e^(2x)*(1) which is not zero, meaning you have a set of linearly independent vectors.. Sorry it is my first time using this and I dont know how to write properly yet.

Comment: Here is a guide to Mathjax [http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference]

Comment: Reminder to edit your answer.